# Need help centering text under icons [tailwind.css]

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am successfully able to recreate the icons with the lines in between using flex, but I cannot figure out how I would center the text under each graphic. The lines in between each icon are throwing this off.

**This is what I am trying to recreate:**

[image]

I have created a CodePen to help demonstrate this issue. Does any one have any ideas?

https://codepen.io/tcj12345/pen/ZEmJRvE

```
  
<div class="bg-black m-40 p-10">
<div class="flex flex-col justify-start gap-4 relative w-full items-stretch">
  <div class="flex flex-row justify-between relative items-center mb-4 mx-24">
    <img
      src="https://file.rendit.io/n/4Fw6iZv56g6sOmbhDsaj.svg"
      class="min-h-0 min-w-0 relative w-24 shrink-0"
    />
    <img
      src="https://file.rendit.io/n/UPVGYkobiO5RjR9Leriz.svg"
      class="min-h-0 min-w-0 relative"
    />
    <img
      src="https://file.rendit.io/n/w3IQhkE8ThXPjrMHQ3Dm.svg"
      class="min-h-0 min-w-0 relative w-24 shrink-0"
    />
    <img
      src="https://file.rendit.io/n/CnE2O9Xwja9IAuSpEDpU.svg"
      class="min-h-0 min-w-0 relative"
    />
    <img
      src="https://file.rendit.io/n/XcqMhAwm97kBGlEuLdbV.svg"
      class="min-h-0 min-w-0 relative w-24 shrink-0"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-row justify-start mr-12 gap-[244px] relative items-center">
    <div class="whitespace-nowrap text-3xl font-['Poppins'] font-bold tracking-[-0.56] leading-[30.8px] text-white relative w-[283px] shrink-0">
      True Representation
    </div>
    <div class="text-3xl font-['Poppins'] font-bold tracking-[-0.56] leading-[30.8px] text-white mr-3 relative w-[180px] shrink-0">
      Accountable
    </div>
    <div class="whitespace-nowrap text-3xl font-['Poppins'] font-bold tracking-[-0.56] leading-[30.8px] text-white relative w-[213px] shrink-0">
      Proven Process
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-row justify-start ml-3 gap-[171px] relative items-center">
    <div class="text-center text-xl font-['SF_Pro'] tracking-[-0.42] leading-[25.2px] text-white mr-10 relative w-64 shrink-0">
      Negotiations and contracts without the headache
    </div>
    <div class="text-center text-xl font-['SF_Pro'] tracking-[-0.42] leading-[25.2px] text-white relative w-64 shrink-0">
      You will have professional advice every step of the way
    </div>
    <div class="text-center text-xl font-['SF_Pro'] tracking-[-0.42] leading-[25.2px] text-white relative w-[303px] shrink-0">
      This is about you and your home. Let's not make it complicated
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reworking the structure such that each section is in its own column in an equal-width 3-column grid. This ensures the icons and the text would be centered relative to each other, and take up the same amount of width. Then, use absolute positioning to overlay the lines:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="bg-black m-40 p-10">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-5 text-center text-white relative z-0">
    <div class="absolute -z-10 h-0.5 bg-white left-[calc(((100%-(theme(spacing.5)*2))/6)+54px)] right-[calc(50%+54px)] top-12"></div>
    <div class="absolute -z-10 h-0.5 bg-white left-[calc(50%+54px)] right-[calc(((100%-(theme(spacing.5)*2))/6)+54px)] top-12"></div>
    <div class="space-y-4">
      <img src="https://file.rendit.io/n/4Fw6iZv56g6sOmbhDsaj.svg" class="w-24 mx-auto !mb-8"/>
      <div class="text-3xl font-['Poppins'] font-bold tracking-[-0.56] leading-[30.8px]">True Representation</div>
      <div class="text-xl font-['SF_Pro'] tracking-[-0.42] leading-[25.2px]">Negotiations and contracts without the headache</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space-y-4">
      <img src="https://file.rendit.io/n/w3IQhkE8ThXPjrMHQ3Dm.svg" class="w-24 mx-auto !mb-8"/>
      <div class="text-3xl font-['Poppins'] font-bold tracking-[-0.56] leading-[30.8px]">Accountable</div>
      <div class="text-xl font-['SF_Pro'] tracking-[-0.42] leading-[25.2px]">You will have professional advice every step of the way</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space-y-4">
      <img src="https://file.rendit.io/n/XcqMhAwm97kBGlEuLdbV.svg" class="w-24 mx-auto !mb-8"/>
      <div class="text-3xl font-['Poppins'] font-bold tracking-[-0.56] leading-[30.8px]">Proven Process</div>
      <div class="text-xl font-['SF_Pro'] tracking-[-0.42] leading-[25.2px]">This is about you and your home. Let's not make it complicated</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To further explain the `calc()`s:

`calc(((100%-(theme(spacing.5)*2))/6)+54px)` is derived from:

1. `theme(spacing.5)` the column gap length.
2. `theme(spacing.5) * 2` the space taken by all the column gaps (2).
3. `100% - (theme(spacing.5) * 2)` the space taken by content *not* including the column gaps.
4. `(100% - (theme(spacing.5) * 2)) / 3` the space available for one column.
5. `(100% - (theme(spacing.5) * 2)) / 6` the space available for one column divided by 2. This gives us the mid-point for the icon circle.
6. Add `54px` to offset from the icon circle:

   1. The circle width is `96px`.
   2. Half is `48px`.
   3. Add `6px` for extra gap.

`calc(50%+54px)` is derived from:

1. `50%` is middle of the middle icon circle.
2. `54px` is same as `6` above.